# how can I improve performance for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have been battling for ages on how to complete a data task that I have, I have tried doing in c# as I am proficient at this, but its was taking forever!!! so I have decided to do in SQL Server, however it looks like it is still going to take forever, maybe as long as 20 days to complete.

Does anyone know any more efficient ways to write my stored procedure?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TotalWins]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @meeting_date DATE;
    DECLARE @idStore INT;
    DECLARE @race_idStore INT;
    DECLARE @runner_id INT;

    SET @idStore = 0;
    SET @race_idStore = -1;
    SET @runner_id = 0;

    WHILE(@idStore IS NOT NULL)  
    BEGIN
        SET @race_idStore = -1;
        SET @runner_id = 0;

        SELECT 
            @idStore = MIN(runners.id)
        FROM
            dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners AS runners
        WHERE
            runners.id > @idStore;

        IF @idStore IS NOT NULL  
        BEGIN   
            SELECT 
                @runner_id = runners.runner_id, @meeting_date = races.meeting_date
            FROM
                dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners AS runners
            INNER JOIN 
                dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races AS races ON races.race_id = runners.race_id
            WHERE
                runners.id > @idStore;

            INSERT INTO dbHorseRacing.dbo.total_wins
                SELECT 
                    @idStore, COUNT(*) AS total_wins 
                FROM 
                    dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners AS runners
                INNER JOIN 
                    dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races AS races ON races.race_id = runners.race_id 
                WHERE 
                    runners.runner_id = @runner_id
                    AND races.meeting_date < @meeting_date
                    AND runners.finish_position = 1;
        END
    END
END
```

I am updating this with question with the ddl and a data sample for the races and runners table. Sorry that they are quite large...

race sample date:
race_id meeting_id  meeting_date    course  conditions  race_name   race_abbrev_name    race_type_id    race_type   race_num    going   direction   class   draw_advantage  num_fences  handicap    all_weather seller  claimer apprentice  maiden  amateur num_runners num_finishers   rating  group_race  min_age max_age distance_yards  added_money official_rating speed_rating    private_handicap    scheduled_time  off_time    winning_time_disp   winning_time_secs   standard_time_disp  standard_time_secs  loaded_at
-1  2941    2003-07-03  Newbury Arab Race   The Emirates Arabian International  Arab Race   12  Flat    1   Good    Left Handed 1   High numbers best in large fields, especially in very soft ground.  NULL    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   8   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1320    0   NULL    NULL    NULL    2003-07-03 18:10:00.000 2003-07-03 00:00:00.000 0:00.00 0   1:14.38 74.379997253418 0x00000000000007DB

race ddl:

```
[dbo].[historic_races]
(
    [race_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [meeting_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [meeting_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [course] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [conditions] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [race_name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [race_abbrev_name] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [race_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [race_type] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [race_num] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [going] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [direction] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [class] [tinyint] NULL,
    [draw_advantage] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [num_fences] [tinyint] NULL,
    [handicap] [tinyint] NULL,
    [all_weather] [tinyint] NULL,
    [seller] [tinyint] NULL,
    [claimer] [tinyint] NULL,
    [apprentice] [tinyint] NULL,
    [maiden] [tinyint] NULL,
    [amateur] [tinyint] NULL,
    [num_runners] [tinyint] NULL,
    [num_finishers] [tinyint] NULL,
    [rating] [int] NULL,
    [group_race] [int] NULL,
    [min_age] [tinyint] NULL,
    [max_age] [tinyint] NULL,
    [distance_yards] [int] NULL,
    [added_money] [float] NULL,
    [official_rating] [int] NULL,
    [speed_rating] [int] NULL,
    [private_handicap] [int] NULL,
    [scheduled_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [off_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [winning_time_disp] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [winning_time_secs] [float] NULL,
    [standard_time_disp] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [standard_time_secs] [float] NULL,
    [loaded_at] [timestamp] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [race_id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample date for runners:

```
runner_id   race_id name    foaling_date    colour  distance_travelled  form_figures    gender  age bred    cloth_number    stall_number    num_fences_jumped   long_handicap   how_easy_won    in_race_comment official_rating official_rating_type    speed_rating    speed_rating_type   private_handicap    private_handicap_type   trainer_name    trainer_id  owner_name  owner_id    jockey_name jockey_id   jockey_claim    dam_name    dam_id  sire_name   sire_id dam_sire_name   dam_sire_id forecast_price  forecast_price_decimal  starting_price  starting_price_decimal  betting_text    position_in_betting finish_position amended_position    unfinished  distance_beaten distance_won    distance_behind_winner  prize_money tote_win    tote_place  days_since_ran  last_race_type_id   last_race_type  last_race_beaten_fav    weight_pounds   penalty_weight  over_weight tack_hood   tack_visor  tack_blinkers   tack_eye_shield tack_eye_cover  tack_cheek_piece    tack_pacifiers  tack_tongue_strap   id  total_wins
```

1   82  401251  David Jack  2010-03-21  CH  143 NULL    C   2   UK  4   3   NULL    NULL    NULL    slowly into stride, took keen hold and soon in touch, pushed along and kept on same pace inside final furlong   NULL    NULL    32  Flat    18  Flat    B J Meehan  9262    Roldvale Limited    2311    T E Durcan  18761   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8/1 9   9/1 10  op 8/1 tchd 10/1    5   4   NULL    NULL    2   NULL    3.5 216.449996948242    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    129 NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1267937 NULL

runners ddl:

```
[dbo].[historic_runners]
(
    [runner_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [race_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [foaling_date] [date] NULL,
    [colour] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [distance_travelled] [int] NULL,
    [form_figures] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [gender] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL,
    [bred] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [cloth_number] [int] NULL,
    [stall_number] [int] NULL,
    [num_fences_jumped] [int] NULL,
    [long_handicap] [int] NULL,
    [how_easy_won] [int] NULL,
    [in_race_comment] [text] NULL,
    [official_rating] [int] NULL,
    [official_rating_type] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [speed_rating] [int] NULL,
    [speed_rating_type] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [private_handicap] [int] NULL,
    [private_handicap_type] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [trainer_name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [trainer_id] [int] NULL,
    [owner_name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [owner_id] [int] NULL,
    [jockey_name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [jockey_id] [int] NULL,
    [jockey_claim] [int] NULL,
    [dam_name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [dam_id] [int] NULL,
    [sire_name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [sire_id] [int] NULL,
    [dam_sire_name] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [dam_sire_id] [int] NULL,
    [forecast_price] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [forecast_price_decimal] [float] NULL,
    [starting_price] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [starting_price_decimal] [float] NULL,
    [betting_text] [text] NULL,
    [position_in_betting] [int] NULL,
    [finish_position] [int] NULL,
    [amended_position] [int] NULL,
    [unfinished] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [distance_beaten] [float] NULL,
    [distance_won] [float] NULL,
    [distance_behind_winner] [float] NULL,
    [prize_money] [float] NULL,
    [tote_win] [float] NULL,
    [tote_place] [float] NULL,
    [days_since_ran] [int] NULL,
    [last_race_type_id] [int] NULL,
    [last_race_type] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [last_race_beaten_fav] [int] NULL,
    [weight_pounds] [int] NULL,
    [penalty_weight] [int] NULL,
    [over_weight] [int] NULL,
    [tack_hood] [int] NULL,
    [tack_visor] [int] NULL,
    [tack_blinkers] [int] NULL,
    [tack_eye_shield] [int] NULL,
    [tack_eye_cover] [int] NULL,
    [tack_cheek_piece] [int] NULL,
    [tack_pacifiers] [int] NULL,
    [tack_tongue_strap] [int] NULL,
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total_wins] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RunnerRaceID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [runner_id] ASC,
    [race_id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Desired results - total_wins table

```
[dbo].[total_wins]
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [total_wins] [int] NULL
)
```

The "id" on the total wins table corresponds to the id of the runners table, so I have 2mill rows in the runners table, with a unique indicator called id (not to be confused with the runner_id column, which contains duplicate entries as 1 runner can run in lots of races). So I would hope to end up with 2 million rows in the total_wins table, the total wins reflects how many races, the runner has won,prior to the date of the particular race the row relates to.

Any help would be really appreciated!! I have been struggling with this, I even considered flattening down the data and using a big data solution like hadoop, or mongodb.

Thanks 
Laura

Comment: Thank you Marc, for fixing all my typos etc :)

Comment: Loops and Cursors are only used in SQL Server for batching because they are very slow. RDBMS are optimized for a set based performance and you almost never loop over anything other then some administrative tasks. You can make a quick research on declarative vs imperative programming in order to understand how SQL is written for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Davids suggestion about using the group by, and avoiding the loop through, I think this is the potential solution...

```
SELECT runners.id,  count(*) as total_wins 
FROM dbo.historic_runners as runners
    inner join dbo.historic_races as races on races.race_id = runners.race_id 
where races.meeting_date <  
(
    select meeting_date
    FROM dbo.historic_runners as ru
    inner join dbo.historic_races as ra on ra.race_id = ru.race_id 
    where ru.id = runners.id
    ) 
and runners.finish_position = 1
group by runners.id
```

Thanks for you answers on this problem, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

Laura, I do not know the exact properties of your database, so I will only give you general ideas of what could be improved.

#### Detecting what is slow

You will need to test what is slow. Make a copy of your database and try to run the queries without the inserts. And then try to run a lot of inserts without custom selections. This way you will detect whether the writes or the reads are slow in your case. If none of these makes it slow, then something else happens to the table slowing down your process.

#### Take a look at the schema

Take a look whether the schema is adequate, like whether your database is in normal form and if so, in which one. If it is not in normal form, it might be a good idea to convert it to normal form.

#### Indexing

Take a look at indexes. If reads are slow, then you will need to add indexes for the columns which are involved in your query, but make sure you read an article before you do that about indexing if you are not well versed in the area. If writes are slow, then consider removing unnecessary indexes, like those involving columns which are not used in queries.

#### Larger batches

I understand that you are iterating the set by each user, but there are probably not so many races that you need to iterate them one-by-one. You could iterate them by batches of 100, by first getting the minimum, then getting the maximum in a select top 100 query ordering by runners.id. This will probably quicken up your process. Note that in later steps you will put the maximum into the minimum, so you will need only one query to determine limits after the very first iteration.

#### Last but not least

If writes are slow, then you can make a copy of the main table with a lot of indexes, so everything will be quick there and copy only relevant subsets there periodically and use that as a source for the stored procedure, so queries will be quick. This would increase performance, but avoid it if you are not forced to do it, since this adds a lot of maintenance work and a lot of additional possibilities to err.

Comment: Thanks Lajos, I will consider batching it up a bit.

Comment: @LauraBaker I have made other suggestions as well. You might want to take a look into them.